# Jenkins - NGINX reverse proxy broken

Tags: nginx, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I just moved our jenkins to a new machine behind a reverse proxy, before it was straight on the intranet. And I've started seeing the error "It appears that your reverse proxy setup is broken."

So I copied the recommended nginx config straight, modifying slightly for our needs but the warning remains, leaving me slightly confused and posting here.

```
upstream jenkins {
  keepalive 32; # keepalive connections
  server 127.0.0.1:8080; # jenkins ip and port
}

server {
  listen          80;       # Listen on port 80 for IPv4 requests

  server_name     jenkins.domain.tld;

  #this is the jenkins web root directory (mentioned in the /etc/default/jenkins file)
  root            /usr/share/jenkins;

  access_log      /var/log/nginx/jenkins/access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/jenkins/error.log;
  ignore_invalid_headers off; #pass through headers from Jenkins which are considered invalid by Nginx server.

  location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
    #rewrite all static files into requests to the root
    #E.g /static/12345678/css/something.css will become /css/something.css
    rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
  }

  location /userContent {
    #have nginx handle all the static requests to the userContent folder files
    #note : This is the $JENKINS_HOME dir
    root /var/lib/jenkins/;
    if (!-f $request_filename){
      #this file does not exist, might be a directory or a /**view** url
      rewrite (.*) /$1 last;
      break;
    }
    sendfile on;
  }

  location @jenkins {
      sendfile off;
      proxy_pass         http://jenkins;
      proxy_redirect     default;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

      #this is the maximum upload size
      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;
      proxy_request_buffering    off; # Required for HTTP CLI commands in Jenkins > 2.54
      proxy_set_header Connection ""; # Clear for keepalive
  }

  location / {
    # Optional configuration to detect and redirect iPhones
    if ($http_user_agent ~* '(iPhone|iPod)') {
      rewrite ^/$ /view/iphone/ redirect;
    }

    try_files $uri @jenkins;
  }
}
```

So it's reached at `jenkins.domain.tld` and I'm out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this. The requests log properly, nothing in the error log, jenkins seems to work in other ways....but the proxy tests gives a 404?

```
$: curl -iL -e http://jenkins.domain.tld/jenkins/manage    http://jenkins.domain.tld/jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 06:50:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 391
Connection: keep-alive
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /jenkins/administrativeMonitor/hudson.diagnosis.ReverseProxySetupMonitor/test. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Jenkins URL in system config is also set to jenkins.domain.tld.

Comment: Did you fix it in the end? I'm running in a similar issue https://gist.github.com/tuxerrante/b417d54eabc7a870c3bbb97dc9494420